# SSRS Date Parameter Mismatching

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services

I have an issue with SSRS where when posting in a DD/MM/YY value via URL string into a Parameter it decides to read the Day value as the Year, the Month as month, but the Year goes into Day value, for example:

I am inputting the date of 30/08/17 via an ERP System which then generates a string to be used as an URL to generate the report, this date value should then go into a parameter called fiAsOfDate which is Date/Time data type, but at this point it is reading the value as 08/17/1930 inside the Parameter list, even though the URL remains at 30/08/17.

This happens prior to the Query being processed, and the fiAsOfDate parameter then gets formatted through to to MMDDYYYY to be processed within the Query, but the issue is specifically when the parameter is having the value loaded from the URL into the parameter value, and I was hoping if anyone could assist me on this please?

I should also add, this original date is coming from an ERP system which will have regional based date formatting, as it is used internationally, so I cannot restrict myself to one input format, and it should be using regional settings, matching that of the Reporting server that it is based on.

Kind Regards,
James W. Acklam.

Comment: I think you either need the regional setting of the sender in your url, or alter the ERP to always use the same format regardless of its region setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid regional setting issues you can change the date into a known integer or string format: I use CONVERT(NVARCHAR, YourDate, 112) to get a string '20170830'. The regional settings won't recognize that as a date and so won't auto-parse it into MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY. Of course, you'll need to parse that yourself so you can use it in the report, but at least you know the format.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was down to my own misunderstanding that the DataSource I was pulling data from worked only in DMY format. Converting dates from parameters format to DMY format and processing that through the DataSet's query resolved the issue.